# Why my Headphone's not working properly?

Tags: windows-7, headphones

I am facing headphone setup problem in my laptop. I can hear sounds from youtube with my head set. But, i can't hear sound from music files in my computer. I am using windows 7 ultimate 32 bit. I have downloaded and installed the audio driver. I've checked it with another headphone. Still does not work.

Comment: Has this always been a problem or is this something new?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you havent set your mixer propertly[image]

try to adjust mixer for all aplications (for example you will see web browser muted and winamp not)

*To open volume mixer click on speaker icon (next to clock), and than mixer link above.*