# Recording with stereo mix. Have to exclude an application without muting it?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio-recording

Title might be confusing, let me explain.

You know what stereo mix does, right?
Short version: It records all sounds that come out of your system and applications, like music players and games.

I have a very special need to record "some" sounds using stereo mix, but while it records, i would like to spend time doing other things, like browsing the internet, watching Youtube or playing games, and muting them isn't an option, cause no sound, no fun. 
The problem is, that if i record using stereo mix, Youtube or game sounds also gets to be recorded, and that really isn't my intention.

Is there a way to exclude these applications out of stereo mix, so them to not to be recorded?

I am on Windows 8.1. if that matters. For what it's worth, i hope i made myself pretty clear.

Comment: see this question, I hope ti will help. Since I dont have 8.1 I cant test it. http://superuser.com/questions/853679/why-my-headphones-not-working-properly/853683#853683

Comment: Volume mixer can mute an application, means that i would have to play a game or watch videos with no sound. Thanks for try, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in any sound card driver I've ever seen. The stereo mix does not represent a separate bus, so there is no way to have some stuff going to the speakers but only a subset of that stuff going to stereo mix.

But an easy way to do it is to add a second sound "card" ("card" in quotes b/c it could be a USB sound interface). Whatever you don't want recorded with "stereo mix", send to the second sound card and feed your speakers from that.

If you must listen to your regular stuff AND the stereo mix, connect the output of the original sound card (the one on which you're recording "stereo mix") into the Line In of the second card, and set the Line In as a "Listen" source. The output of the second card should now include the first card's stereo mix along with everything else it's playing, and in the mixer controls for that card, you can select how much of each you hear.

Comment: Yeah, i had a feeling that i would receive an answer like that. Very unfortunate that i don't have a second audio card. If that is the only option... will have to buy one. :( still, maybe someone else knows something that we don't. Like, could there be a 3rd party software that could do something about this?

Comment: There is the "virtual audio cable" (or some name similar to that) that basically gives you an all-in-software "sound card" and allows you to send the output to various places. However it only works on 32-bit Windows because the developer doesn't have a code signing cert.

Comment: I will look into it, but can't go back to 32-bit. Not much of a solution, but thanks.